# How to export the data in docker container?

Tags: docker

I'm using the old version of docker(1.9), sometimes will meet a bug(deadlock), I cann't run any command of docker. like docker ps , docker insepct...

The container is still running, can I export the data in container? or where is the data stored in the host machine?

Answer (score 1):

it depends if your data is in a volume or in the container.

See the doc for `docker export`

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/export/

extract `the docker export command does not export the contents of volumes associated with the container.`

if you have volumes, see

https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes

the command `docker cp`

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/

should copy whatever you want from a container to somewhere on the host, but this will be useless for you if most `docker xxx` commands hang
The data is usually stored in /var/lib/docker, but that can change depending upon your docker version and whether you run on Linux, Mac, or Windows

Comment: conetos,  if my container id is ccebd0279e19xxxxx can I find the data in /var/lib/docker？